# How to put images in a different column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I do not know my all my images are in 1 column. Can you please help me put 1 image in 1 column. I would really appreciate it if you could also explain why this is happening. THE PROBLEM ONLY IS HERE @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px). Thank a lot for helping, it means alot. I've been working on these for hours but could not figure it out.
[This is how it looks now, there's some problem with the grid i think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePAlg.png)
[This is how it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6tmP.jpg)

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.container .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container .box .dream {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 34%;
}

.container .box .dream img {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .container .box {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container .box .dream {
        width: 25%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        display: grid;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 2rem auto;
    }
    .container .box {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 5vw);
        grid-gap: 1rem;
    }
    .gallery__img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block;
    }
    .gallery__item--1 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
        /** Alternative Syntax **/
        /* grid-column: 1 / span 2;  */
        /* grid-row: 1 / span 2; */
    }
    .gallery__item--2 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 5;
        /** Alternative Syntax **/
        /* grid-column: 3 / span 2;  */
        /* grid-row: 1 / span 2; */
    }
    .gallery__item--3 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 5;
        grid-row-end: 7;
        /** Alternative Syntax **/
        /* grid-column: 5 / span 4;
      grid-row: 1 / span 5; */
    }
    .gallery__item--4 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 7;
        grid-row-end: 9;
        /** Alternative Syntax **/
        /* grid-column: 1 / span 4;  */
        /* grid-row: 3 / span 3; */
    }
    .gallery__item--5 {
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 7;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 5;
        /** Alternative Syntax **/
        /* grid-column: 1 / span 4; */
        /* grid-row: 6 / span 3; */
    }
    .gallery__item--6 {
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 5;
        grid-row-start: 7;
        grid-row-end: 9;
        /** Alternative Syntax **/
        /* grid-column: 5 / span 4; */
        /* grid-row: 6 / span 3; */
    }
    .gallery__item--7 {
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 5;
        grid-row-start: 5;
        grid-row-end: 7;
    }
    .gallery__item--8 {
        grid-column-start: 5;
        grid-column-end: 7;
        grid-row-start: 5;
        grid-row-end: 7;
    }
    .gallery__item--9 {
        grid-column-start: 5;
        grid-column-end: 7;
        grid-row-start: 7;
        grid-row-end: 9;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="dream">
                <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--1">
                    <img src="/images/1.jpg" alt="Gallery image 1" class="gallery__img">

                    <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--2">
                        <img src="/images/2.jpg" alt="Gallery image 2" class="gallery__img">
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--3">
                        <img src="/images/3.jpg" alt="Gallery image 3" class="gallery__img">
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--4">
                        <img src="/images/4.jpg" alt="Gallery image 4" class="gallery__img">
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--5">
                        <img src="/images/5.jpg" alt="Gallery image 5" class="gallery__img">
                    </figure>

            </div>


            <div class="dream">
                <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--6">
                    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="Gallery image 6" class="gallery__img">
                </figure>
                <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--7">
                    <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="Gallery image 7" class="gallery__img">
                </figure>
                <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--8">
                    <img src="images/8.jpg" alt="Gallery image 8" class="gallery__img">
                </figure>
                <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--9">
                    <img src="images/9.jpg" alt="Gallery image 9" class="gallery__img">
                </figure>


            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't close your div tags in your html file.

```
<body>
    <div class="container grid">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="dream">
                <img src="/images/1.jpg">
                <img src="/images/2.jpg">
                <img src="/images/3.jpg">
                <img src="/images/4.jpg">
                <img src="/images/5.jpg">

            </div>


            <div class="dream">
                <img src="/images/6.jpg">
                <img src="/images/7.jpg">
                <img src="/images/8.jpg">
                <img src="/images/9.jpg">


            </div>
    **</div>
    </div>**
</body>
```

Secondly, it is important for you to use grid in min-width: 1024px

It will be easier to answer you if u'll draw a image you want to have in a result

Answer (score 0):

[If u want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSkUX.png)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container .box {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .dream {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

[or this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yes5N.png)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container .box .dream {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .dream img {
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

sorry, but without image we can't understand what you want to have as a result

here u are
[image]

https://codepen.io/python-maniac/pen/bGqwwoP

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="img1"></div>
  <div class="img2"></div>
  <div class="img3"></div>
  <div class="img4"></div>
  <div class="img5"></div>
  <div class="img6"></div>
  <div class="img7"></div>
  <div class="img8"></div>
  <div class="img9"></div>
</div>

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 0% 0%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img1 img3 img3"
    "img2 img3 img3"
    "img4 img5 img6"
    "img7 img8 img9";
}

.img1 { grid-area: img1; }

.img2 { grid-area: img2; }

.img3 { grid-area: img3; }

.img4 { grid-area: img4; }

.img5 { grid-area: img5; }

.img6 { grid-area: img6; }

.img7 { grid-area: img7; }

.img8 { grid-area: img8; }

.img9 { grid-area: img9; }

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  .grid-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    -ms-grid-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }

  .img1 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .img2 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .img3 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  }

  .img4 {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .img5 {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .img6 {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .img7 {
    -ms-grid-row: 4;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .img8 {
    -ms-grid-row: 4;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .img9 {
    -ms-grid-row: 4;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code and attached a screenshot on how it should look like. Please help me out. I would be really grateful.